# How to preserve data format between fread and fwrite in R

Tags: r, type-conversion, data.table, fwrite, fread

I have a data.table field that is a number but stored as a character. If I save the data.table using `fwrite` as a text file and read it using `fread`, the type of this field changes to integer. Is there a way to preserve the original type of the field without having to coerce later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

Here is a reproducible example :

```
library(data.table)

df <- data.frame(c1 = 1:10, c2 = as.character(11:20))
df <- as.data.table(df)

fwrite(df, "your_address_here", quote = TRUE)

df <- fread("your_address_here", colClasses = c(c2 = "character"))
```

The trick is to set `quote=TRUE` in `fwrite()` and to specify the type of the column in `fread()` with `colClasses` argument, using a named vector.

Comment: Thank you! I used colClasses = list(character = c("c2")) instead. This allows mentioning all character fields that have numeric values as a group.